# kde 5.24 - overview launch key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, kde

I just upgraded my KDE Plasma to 5.24 using an ubuntu ppa. I love the overview function. Right now it launches from Meta-W . How do I get it to launch from Meta alone?

When I try to change the key binding I type the Meta key and the settings screen wants another key. It is as if the Meta key were only a Shift key, and cannot be used alone.

Thanks.

Comment: @David No, it was released on February 8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution in [this Reddit thread.](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/ppxrbg/comment/hd8b5e7/)
The normal trick of setting the shortcut to `Alt+F1` does not work for the now released Overview effect.
However, you can assign the shortcut to your meta key directly using the config files or by running:

```
kwriteconfig5 --file kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta "org.kde.kglobalaccel,/component/kwin,,invokeShortcut,Overview"
```

And then you can reload your KWin settings without restarting KWin by running:

```
qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure
```

Comment: that is fantastic. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want another key, that you can just go to settings -> keybinds
(see : https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/khelpcenter/fundamentals/shortcuts.html)

Search for overview, enter your key.

Screenshot from my french installation:
[image]